# Change CSS top value based on screen size

Tags: css, css-animations

When using CSS bounce key-frames i have set the top of the bounce to 870px, but if I re-size the window the object can bounce past the border of the window, is there any way to change the bounds with the screen size.

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    from, to{
        top: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    50%{
        top: 870px; /*value in question*/
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use media queries for this and change the bounce depending on the screen size.

Comment: Or use a viewport unit/percentage value for top.

Comment: @ManojKumar Using percentages stops the object bouncing at all.

Comment: @Pepo_rasta Using percentages stops the object bouncing at all.

Comment: @Ionut How would the media query account for every screen size?

Comment: Can you create a demo of your full code please?

Comment: @ManojKumar I would but i just looked into view-port units and used those, now the code works(for some reason they work and percentages don't). If you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct, thanks for your help.

Comment: @CianNoonan I can try to explain the problem if you post the code. Otherwise it is worthy of a comment and you can post the answer yourself, mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using view-port units allowed the animation to scale to the screen size. credit to @Manoj Kumar for introducing me to them.